# I am getting a NullPointerException when calling String.length() on a string during BufferedReading that should not be null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, bufferedreader

I am using a method with a `BufferedReader` with `FileReader` to read a file. The file consists of several lines of items separated by multiple white spaces. I am looping through the each line of the file using a `while` loop with the condition that the line I just read isn't `null` or blank.

I read the the first line and then enter the loop and then I get a `NullPointerException` that my line is `null`, but it shouldn't be because I just read it.

```java
public ReadFile(String filename) {
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        String ln;
        ln = br.readLine();

        // loops as long as the last line read is not null or blank
        while (ln != null || ln.length() != 0) {
            //do stuff with ln
            ln = br.readLine();
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I was expecting to loop through reading the file line by line until either the line was `null` or blank (in case the last line is ""). This however does not happen and the line is null when the `while` loop is run. I tried this same exact implementation but in a different file in the `main` function and it worked perfect so I am very confused with what's wrong.

Comment: [Edit] your question and post the entire stack trace for the `NullPointerException` you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Well, basically it's because of your **conditional check**.

The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) says that the method readLine() returns:
**A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached.**

So at the end of the stream you'll get a null. Now, because of the **OR (||)** operator you have in the while loop, your conditional statements will be checked until you find a true statement.

**This is because of ['short-circuits-logical-operators' in Java.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/short-circuit-logical-operators-in-java-with-examples/)**

So you'll check the condition:

> ```
>         ln!=null => false
> ```

and then because the **Or** is searching for a **true** condition, you'll check

> ```
>         ln.length() => and get a NullPointerException
> ```

If you want to avoid this, you can use the **&& (and)** operator with the same conditions.

This way, if the ln is null, you'll check the first condition

> ```
>         ln!=null => false
> ```

and then because the And operator requires every condition to be true to be verified, you'll interrupt the while loop.

> ```
>         while (ln != null && ln.length() != 0){
>             //do stuff with ln
>             ln = br.readLine();
>         }ln = null;
> ```

**Keep in mind** however, that if you have a line that is **empty** "" it's **length will be 0**, so the while loop will **stop**.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think that you can change your code to:

```
while (ln!=null) {
            //we check if the line is not empty
            if(ln.length() !=0) {
                //do your operations
            }
            //read the next line
            ln = br.readLine();
        }
```

The process is to first check if the line is null. If it's not null, then check if it has content. If it does have content, perform your operation on the non-empty, non-null line. In all cases, read the next line.